Is there a global keyboard shortcut to open the latest (incoming) email received by Microsoft Outlook?
When Microsoft Outlook downloads an incoming email, it displays a notification (bottom right) telling the user about the new message. Is there no global keyboard shortcut (usable even outside Outlook) to open that email, which would work in Windows 10 or above no matter what the active window is? It could be specific to Outlook or a generic way to open a notification, but I am not looking for a complex sequence (like opening Outlook, going to email, then going to the inbox, etc.).
The Windows + Shift + V shortcut proposed as a solution to a very similar question unfortunately has no effect (even though Microsoft documents that it should do something).

Unfortunately, there isn’t a global keyboard shortcut specifically designed to open the latest incoming email in Microsoft Outlook.
Generally speaking, when using shortcut keys in Outlook, the premise is that you have opened and used Outlook when using shortcut keys to help make it more convenient to use.
For shortcut methods that can be used in Outlook, please refer to this document: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#PickTab=Classic_Outlook

The closest you're going to get is probably:

CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+WIN+O = Open Outlook
CTLR+E = Focus the search bar
received:today
ENTER
CTRL+ALT+A = Include all items (mailboxes, calendar, etc)

Maybe creating an AutoHotkey or Microsoft PowerToys script might allow you to pin a shortcut to the taskbar for these actions.
